# How do I get rid of a warning due to iteration through NSManagedObjects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSArrayController` filled with `NSMutableDictionary` objects. The following code is working without any problem but I would like to get rid of the compiler warning I get. `Collection expression type 'NSManagedObject *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:onjects:count:'`
As far as I understand, I get this error because the array controller COULD have also different types of objects inside that do not have a key value. But in my case I am only using mutable dictionaries so it should be ok.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)getlist:(id)sender{
    checkedchecks = 0;
    for (NSManagedObject *a in imagescontroller.arrangedObjects)
    {
        for (NSString* key in a) {

            if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[a valueForKey:key]] isEqualToString: @"1"])
            {
                checkedchecks += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init] ;
    [alert setMessageText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)checkedchecks ]];
    [alert runModal];
}
```

How could i get rid of this annoying warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you typing `a` as an `NSManagedObject *` if it's an `NSMutableDictionary *`?

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *a in imagescontroller.arrangedObjects)
```

is probably what you want.

Comment: *a is a leftover, already fixed, thanks for telling. and also your change worked great! thank you (feel pretty stupid now as the answer was obvious... )